# Yarn doesn't "see" cmd/PowerShell command 'copy'

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I have freshly installed yarn (via corepack) and there is this weird problem. I have scripts in package.json that use `copy` command, for example:

```
"t": "copy src\\index_dev.html src\\index.html /y"
```

However, running `yarn t` returns this error:

```
command not found: copy
```

If I simply run `copy` in the **same** terminal window it does run. I suspect I need to write some PATH var, but not sure which exactly. The OS is Windows 11.

Is there anything can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Not an answer to my question (so I'm only leaving a comment) but probably a better solution is to use npm package copyfiles rather than platform-depended copy command